# .htaccess Rewrite/Redirect mod or PHP script

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

So currently E-commerce company I'm working for is in transition from an .NET based platform to the Magento PHP based site. The issue I'm running into is that we have 1000's of our current landing pages ranked well on search engines. There's no way for me to 301 all of these pages within the new platform - Magento, and I know I can't add 1000's of static redirects to the .htaccess file because of performance issues.

So my question is this, Is there a way to create rewrite or redirect rules for variables within our DB that generate the indexed pages URL's. If there is, performance wise would it be smarter to do this solely with the .htaccess file, just PHP Scripts or a combination of both?

Here's a sample of one of our current URLs and sample of what we'd like it to be redirected to:

Current URL
/Clear_For_Life-Aquariums_Bowls-AT-70_180-AQAQ-ct.html

Here's a breakdown of the data we use to generate the rewrite;

1. /Clear_For_Life = VendorName Column in DB
2. Aquariums_Bowls = Subcategory Column in DB
3. AT = VendorCode Column in DB
4. 70_180 = PriceRange Column in DB
5. AQAQ = CategoryId Column in DB

Desired URL to be Redirected to;
/clear-for-life-aquariums-bowl

Any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a database call and php script really going to be more efficient than an htaccess file being processed by apache?

Comment: I'm just not sure if a combination of rewriting and redirection only using the .htaccess file could even handle the complexities of rewriting and redirecting the old URL. Your question pretty much encompasses part of my question as well though would it?

Comment: Do you have 1000's of static pages, one 1 dynamic page parsing the request url?

Comment: One dynamic page parsing the request url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is this, Is there a way to create rewrite or redirect rules for variables within our DB that generate the indexed pages URL's. If there is, performance wise would it be smarter to do this solely with the .htaccess file, just PHP Scripts or a combination of both?

This sounds like a job for [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). You'll need access to either the server or vhost config and create a map. You can use this mapping to call a script that can fetch something from your DB, then decide what the new URI needs to look like. The simplest usage of `RewriteMap` could be:

```
RewriteMap remap prg:/path/to/script
```

And later you can simply do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${remap:$1|$1} [L]
```

The `/path/to/script` would need to take an input like `Clear_For_Life-Aquariums_Bowls-AT-70_180-AQAQ-ct.html`, parse it, and correctly output `clear-for-life-aquariums-bowl`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jon I think this may be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change case or replace characters ('_' to '-') using mod rewrite.

Why can't you 301 all these pages?
If they are being accessed with .NET then where ever you do the routing / parse the url there should be a line of code to do the php redirect.

Comment: The character replacement can be acheived with mod rewrite like this;Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
 
RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=4]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=uscor:Yes]
 
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscor} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://d.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: The old .NET server will be gone once we make the transition.

Answer (score 0):

I say use htaccess, and write a simple utility to generate said htaccess file from a list of the 301 details.